# Ubuntu boot problems after first installation

Tags: installation, boot

I just installed Ubuntu and I have problems.

I did everything that tutorial said so, but when installation finished, I restarted and I chose Ubuntu as boot but when I booted, black screen showed and then Purple screen of Ubuntu showed with no letters on it and I stucked to it.

Whats the problem?

Comment: What tutorial and which version of Ubuntu 32 or 64?

Comment: Tutorial, on Ubuntu website. I chose 64bit cos I use Windows 7 64bit if thats the case...Did I do something wrong and selected 62 bit?

Comment: I see, 64 bit was the right choice but its always good to make sure. Did you make a cd or a live usb? I would try to redo the live cd/usb sometimes things during that step can get messed up/corrupted.

Comment: I installed it via USB...

Comment: Ok :) Was everything working when you tested the usb? No problems with using the os via the usb? This black screen issue seems to be a graphic's problem (might need to install some linux based drivers). If you know the graphic's card I would look it up and see if anyone else has problem with it on linux os

Comment: Everything was fine,installation fine etc. Finished installation, restarted and then I booted to Windows 7 accidently and then CHDSK appeared it, searching something. After that, I again restarted pc, booted to Ubuntu, Purple screen shows, black screen for 2 seconds and then again Purple screen with no letters and then I am stucked forever...What should I do?

Comment: I see you have a dual boot setup, and did CHDSK report that there was any bad section (if you don't remember thats fine)? I would boot up with the usb os and do a test on the hard drive make sure its not the hard-drive. It could be the hard-drive is faulty but I think that CHDSK just corrupted the linux partition n you just need to reinstall the linux os. Hope this all helps!

Comment: I dont want to risk losing Windows as well.. I mean, some article say if you either unistall, I dunno, you could lose the ability to boot to any OS...No, CHDSK hadnt found any bad sections or files. No problems detected it said. How do I reinstall Ubuntu anyways?And what if CHDSK again appears when I boot to Windows?

Comment: Have a look to the answers of this [question](http://askubuntu.com/q/162075/32413) about black screen